# Самообновляющийся таймер в jlabel swing java

Tags: java, swing

Как можно реализовать таймер, и так чтобы таймер в jlabel каждую секунду обновлялся?

```
        ActionListener checkAction = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("logoff");
            }
        };

        javax.swing.Timer checker = new javax.swing.Timer(timer, checkAction);
        checker.start();
```

Вот у меня после некоторого времени должно выполнятся событие, как тут сделать обновление в jLabel, если это событие еще не наступило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// подтолкну на мысли, коли так

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
        // конструируем таймер, вызывающий обработчик событий
        // через каждые 10 секунд
        Timer t = new Timer(10000, listener);
        t.start();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Остановить время?");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

// пишем класс TimePrinter
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimePrinter implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("Это тикает время, которого так мало! " + now);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    }

}
```

Таймер будет обновляться каждые десять секунд, пока вы не жмакните по кнопке OK.